# Wrong hex color coding in ggplot pdf export

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a problem with the color coding for ggplot pdf output. I would like my pdf export to have the hex color "#6e302e". This works when I see the output within R but when I export and doublecheck with InDesign color picker the color is "#663330". Is it possible to fix this?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)


### create random sf polygon
pol = st_sfc(st_polygon(list(cbind(c(0,3,3,0,0),c(0,0,3,3,0)))))

a <- ggplot() + geom_sf(data = pol, lwd = 0.1, color = "black", fill = "#6e302e")  

a

ggsave("test.pdf", plot = last_plot(), device = "pdf", width = 15, height = 12, units = c("cm"))
```

EDIT:

I am using newest R version on OSX.

This is the color value from R output:
[image: This is the color value from R]

This is the color value from the pdf:
[image: This is the color value from the PDF]

Comment: The color is correct for me. (Tested in Windows 10, `ggplot2_3.3.2`). Do you have a "web safe" color selection option selected in the InDesign color picker? Can you check with a different tool?

Comment: this is weird. I don't really know what "web safe" color selection option is but I tried with color sync utility and the colors are also different.

Comment: I think this is more of an InDesign question, than an R question. Perhaps open the pdf with Inkscape or some other software to check.

Answer (score 2):

I fail to open the pdf with InDesign (CS5.5) natively, but I'm no expert on InDesign anyway. However, when opening the PDF with Photoshop (also CS5.5), it only gets the correct color if I'm importing the PDF using the sRGB colour profile that's also shown in your screenshots. If I'm opening it with the default RGB profile, I get a color value of R: 109, G: 47, B: 45, while the color you want is R: 110, G: 48, B: 46.

I believe it depends on how you import the PDF into InDesign. As I said, I cannot natively open PDF, just paste it as a vector image. If I use the eyedropper, InDesign prompts a warning, saying that it's just the color values are based on the RGB desktop version with low resolution. What I get, is again R: 109, G: 47, B: 45.

Your problem could possibly be solved by opening the PDF with some other program (e.g., PS, Illustrator), choosing the sRGB profile to import it with, save it to another file format (e.g. .ai), and then open in InDesign. An easier option surely would be to just change the color of the image within InDesign.

Moreover, after a small internet research, I found that importing PDFs with the right colour profile in InDesign is not really straightforward, and there seems to be no option to convert into sRGB right away, as there is in Photoshop. In fact, 'Place...' converts the pdf into RGB and in consequence, the colour changes slightly.